# what does this macro mean ? #define UNUSED(x) ((x)=(x))

Tags: c++, c

what does this macro mean ? I just find the following macro in source files:

```
#define UNUSED(x) ((x)=(x))
```

Comment: To nicen up pre-processor output with some ascii-art? ;-)

Comment: Oh, wow, that's the wrong way to implement `(void)x` to avoid an unused variable warning. Using assignment has side effects, so that definition doesn't mean what it says on the tin.

Comment: In addition to what @kfsone noted, `x` might have no accessible assignment operator at all. Use `#define UNUSED(x) (void)x` instead.

Comment: It's also rather dubious when `x` is uninitialized, and that's a real possibility for "unused" variables.

Comment: Sigh. It's a workaround for "helpful" compiler writers that tells you that you've done something that doesn't fit their style guidelines.

Answer (score 9):

It is probably there to suppress compiler warnings of unused variables/arguments to functions.  You could also use this:

```
// C++ only
void some_func(int /*x*/)
```

Or

```
// C and C++
void some_func(int x)
{
    (void)x;
}
```

Or your compiler may support a flag to do so, but these are portable and won't skip over valid warnings.

Comment: You can only use anonymous parameters in C++; they are not allowed in C.  (The question is tagged with both C and C++, so you're not wrong, but you haven't given an important caveat to your suggestion.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Tagging questions with C and C++ should be disallowed...  Good point though, I'll make it clear.

Comment: @EdS. it should be allowed - but only if user correctly solves quiz about differences between C and C++.

Comment: @el.pescado: Hehe, ok, fair enough

Answer (score 5):

Use it to get rid of any compiler warning referring an unused variable.

Answer (score 2):

It silence the compiler from complaining that a variable is not used.

Other ways to do it :

- completely remove the variable : `void foo( int )`
- out comment the variable       : `void foo( int /* value */ )`
- use that macro                 : `void foo( int value ){ UNUSED(value); }`

Answer (score 2):

Some compilers issue a warning about unused variables - variables that are defined but never referenced. Sometimes you have code that references a variable only under some conditional ifdefs (only on some platforms or only in debug) and it is inconvenient to duplicate those conditions at the point the variable is defined. A macro like this can be used to suppress the unused variable warning in such cases.